# How to use Kendo grid with Ember js

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js, kendo-grid, kendo-dataviz

After searching throughout the web pertaining to this topic, nothing much came up so I though I might as well post this question as it may concern future web developers. I'm new to ember.

I'm trying to create a Kendo grid through the Ember framework. After importing Kendo files into my Broc file, I'm unsure how to initialize it. Is it possible to create a Ember component that calls the Kendo initializers in jQuery? How could that look?

Can an ember models directly map attributes to initialize Kendo grid? I'd like to take advantage of Kendo's virtualization feature.

Comment: Did you  manage to make this work? I'm facing the same situation now, thanks

Comment: @novascape Yeah, create a component. jQuery is enabled in ember components. Initialize the grid under some initialization function, on(... didInsertElement, or init) on a div inside your handle bar template.All the features of Kendo will be set upon initialization. You pass in param and data (or if remotely fetching data) to your component